# Windows 8 printing Postscript file programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-8, printing, dllimport, postscript

I've spotted a strange problem while **printing a Postscript file**.

So here is my setup:

I have a **Windows 8 PC**, on this PC there is an **C# application** "NetworkPrintTest.exe", which, when executed, should open a PDF, generate a Postscript file and ultimately should print it.
But it doesn't do anything. I don't get an error but it won't print either.
The same program runs error free on windows 7 and i even get the printer to print the file.

As mentioned above the .ps file is generated successfully on both operating systems but the printing failes.

Here is my source code which should print the file.

```
public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, int dwCount, params string[] docName)
        {
            int dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool flag = false;
            di.pDocName = "print document";
            if (docName.Length > 0)
                di.pDocName = docName[0];
            di.pDataType = "RAW";
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        flag = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            if (!flag)
            {
                Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return flag;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
```

I used some DLL imports

```
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("winspool.Drv", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int capindex);

[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);
```

I've found that the **GDI32.dll differs** in version but i don't see any problems so far.

Windows 7 -> 6.1.7601.18275

Windows 8 -> 6.2.9200.16654

My Application is written in **C#** in **.Net Framework 2.0**

Answer (score 4):

With Windows Vista onwards you need to use the data type "XPS_PASS" instead of "RAW" for printers with XPS based drivers.

Comment: Tony, you saved my day. I was digging for this problem. When I replaced "RAW" with "XPS_PASS" it worked as expected.

Comment: I created a solution for this on nuget at https://www.nuget.org/packages/RawPrint/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will test this asap and see if it worked. Thanks so far +1