# How to make RawPrinterHelper work in both XPS_PATH and RAW data types?

Tags: c#, printing

I am using [RawPrinterHelper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091/en-us) for printing. And it works fine with Windows 7 and previous versions.
When we tried it with a printer installed on Windows 8 pc, it did not work.

After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975988/windows-8-printing-postscript-file-programmatically) I've learned that I have to set dataType variable to "XPS_PASS" instead of "RAW". Setting it to "XPS_PASS" works fine on windows 8 by the way.

But in my environment, there are windows 8s and windows 7s and XPs also.

Is it possible to make this switch programmatically?

How can I set pDataType variable to "RAW" for windows 7 and lower operating systems, and to "XPS_PASS" to windows 8?

Edit: After a couple of hours digging google I've found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779300) article. Here it says:

> 1. Call GetPrinterDriver to retrieve the DRIVER_INFO_8 struct.
> 2. Check DRIVER_INFO_8::dwPrinterDriverAttributes for the PRINTER_DRIVER_XPS flag.
> 3. Choose your datatype based on the presence or absence of the
>      flag:
>
>    - If the flag is set, use ‘XPS_PASS’
>    - If the flag is not set, use ‘RAW’

I am not familiar with unmanaged code, but I've tried the followig:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GetPrinterDriver(IntPtr hPrinter, string pEnvironment, uint Level, IntPtr pDriverInfo, int cbBuf, out int pcbNeeded);



 private static void GetPrinterDataType(IntPtr hPrinter )
    {
        IntPtr driverInfo = new IntPtr();
        driverInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        int buf_len = 0;
        int IntPtrSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));

        int a = GetPrinterDriver(hPrinter, "", 8, driverInfo, 0, out buf_len);

        driverInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buf_len);

        a = GetPrinterDriver(hPrinter, "", 8, driverInfo, buf_len, out buf_len);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            if (i == 12 || i == 15 || i == 11 || i == 14)
                continue;

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(driverInfo, IntPtrSize * i);
            Console.WriteLine("DRIVER INFO {0}: {1}", i, Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr));
        }

    }
```

I am calling this method after OpenPrinter() method of the RawPrinterHelper class. But the dwPrinterDriverAttributes (number 21) is empty.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Output of the method]

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same thing.  My workaround solution was simply to try the other mode if the first failed.  Did you have any luck solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to work out how to get a value showing for the dwPrinterDriverAttributes field.

I added this definition of the DRIVER_INFO_8 structure to my solution (found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/DRIVER_INFO_8.html)).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct DRIVER_INFO_8
{
    public uint cVersion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pEnvironment;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pDriverPath;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pDataFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pConfigFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pHelpFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pDependentFiles;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pMonitorName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pDefaultDataType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszzPreviousNames;
    FILETIME ftDriverDate;
    UInt64 dwlDriverVersion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszMfgName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszOEMUrl;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszHardwareID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszProvider;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszPrintProcessor;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszVendorSetup;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszzColorProfiles;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszInfPath;
    public uint dwPrinterDriverAttributes;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string pszzCoreDriverDependencies;
    FILETIME ftMinInboxDriverVerDate;
    UInt64 dwlMinInboxDriverVerVersion;
}
```

Then I added this line of code to what you have above in your GetPrinterDriverDataType() method:

```
var info = (DRIVER_INFO_8)Marshal.PtrToStructure(driverInfo, typeof(DRIVER_INFO_8));
```

Now you will be able to see what the dwPrinterDriverAttributes field is populated with.

EDIT: Updated the protection level of dwPrinterDriverAttributes to be public so it can be accessed/viewed.

Also worth noting this (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc244841.aspx)):

```
dwPrinterDriverAttributes: A bit field that specifies attributes of the printer driver.
```

So I've converted the uint to a BitArray and checked to see if the PRINTER_DRIVER_XPS flag/bit is set.

i.e.

```
PRINTER_DRIVER_XPS flag = 0x00000002
```

So we need to check the second bit.  I do this with the following:

```
var value = (int)info.dwPrinterDriverAttributes;
BitArray b = new BitArray(new int[] { value } );
bool[] bits = new bool[b.Count];
b.CopyTo(bits, 0);

if (bits[1]) 
    Console.WriteLine("flag set");
else
    Console.WriteLine("flag not set");
```

Comment: PRINTER_DRIVER_XPS is only available on Windows 8, I solved this problem by iterating through the dependent files and if I found one that ended in -pipelineconfig.xml then I know it is an XPS based driver.

Comment: I see this is an old thread but be sure to call Marshal.FreeHGlobal() after you are finished with the memory you allocated with Marshal.AllocHGlobal().  The garbage collector will not clean it up on your behalf and you will wind up with a memory leak.