# Java raw Postscript printing, sending XPS_PASS (Windows specific)

Tags: java, printing, windows-8, windows-8.1, xps

Newer XPS print drivers (almost all Windows 8 print drivers) require DOCINFO.pDataType = "XPS_PASS" (instead of "RAW") to pipe raw print jobs (Postscript/PCL/ZPL/etc).
([Send Postscript Document to Printer using VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078852/send-postscript-document-to-printer-using-vc/17216633))
([How to make RawPrinterHelper work in both XPS_PATH and RAW data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807081/how-to-make-rawprinterhelper-work-in-both-xps-path-and-raw-data-types))

Other than using something like JNA, is there a way to do this in a Java applet/application?
I can use JNA, and plan to use it for printer management, but I'd rather the actual printing not have to delve into JNA - Win32 API territory.

NOTE: I also want to avoid having to pipe directly to 9100, serial ports, etc.  Makes more sense to make use of already detected/configured printers.

***WORKAROUND:  I've had success using JNA and JOB_INFO to send "XPS_PASS".  Can use PRINTER_INFORMATION_4 and DOCINFO_4/DOCINFO_8 (implement structs yourself) to detect if XPS_PASS or RAW should be sent.  See C++ examples***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNI is the only choice right now.  Should probably be filed as a bug report to Java issue tracker.

JDK8 source:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/WPrinterJob.cpp#l999

JDK9 source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/c0ed608fc7d2/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/WPrinterJob.cpp#l1060

Unfortunately, it is not possible as the DOCINFO.pDataType is hardcoded to "RAW", and there does not appear to be any other entrypoints to printing in the JVM.